# How to add custom DIV using droppble function of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add some custom `<div>` elements on drag-and-drop of a `<div>`. Here is my [JSFiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/5DCZw/1118/).

My purpose is to add custom `<div>` on drag-and-drop of `<div>` named '1' , '2' , and '3' to the below `<div>`. On drop of `<div>` '1', I have set `innerHTML` text to `"Hello World."`. It works for all other `s. However, I still have some issues.

My first issue is that once I dropped `<div>` '1' , it will not able to drag this `<div>` again. How can I achieve this?

My other issue is I have simply set `innerHTML` of `<div>` to `"Hello World."`. But what I want is every time when any `<div>` dropped to this `<div>`, it will append my custom `<div>` with text `"Hello World."`, not just set `innerHTML`.

Please help me. I am looking for some appropriate suggestions.

```js
$(function() {
    $(".draggable").draggable({
        connectToSortable: '#droppable',
        revert: true,
        helper: 'clone',
        start: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).fadeTo(0, 1);
        }
    });


    $("#droppable").droppable({
        hoverClass: 'active',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            this.innerHTML = '<div>Hello World.</div>';
        }
    });
    
    $("#droppable").sortable();
    
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 11pt;
}
.draggable {
    width: 250px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #e6eaff;
    border: 2px solid #3399cc;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding: 4px;
    cursor: default;
}
.active {
    border: 2px solid #6699ff;
}
#droppable {
    font-size: 14pt;
    height:100px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color:gray;
}
#droppableHolder {
    margin-top: 5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="draggable">1</div>
<div class="draggable">2</div>
<div class="draggable">3</div>
<div id="droppableHolder">
    Drop in this text box:<br />
    <br />
    <div id="droppable"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have edited my answer, plz check this. @Sumitpatel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `append` instead of `innerHTML`.

But since this will be triggered on each `drop`, you'll need to validate that the `drop` was triggered by one of the draggable, not one of your custom div. You could do it like this:

```
     if (ui.draggable.hasClass('draggable')) {
              var newDiv = $('<div>Hello World.</div>');
              $(this).append(newDiv);
          }
     }
```

Also, as said in previous answer, remove `connectToSortable`, you don't need it.

http://jsfiddle.net/y9q5hu01/2/

EDIT:

To be able to use `connnectToSortable`, you can modify `html` content of the dropped div instead of creating a new one. Like this:

```
   drop: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.draggable.hasClass('draggable')) {
            ui.draggable.html('<div>Hello World.</div>').removeClass('draggable');
        }
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y9q5hu01/3/

Comment: your answer is work fine but i want to append item with sortable. Mean wherever i drop it other items must sort up or down and drop my custom div.

Comment: hello i have  Drag div and Drop In Direct my custom Div But Not Droppable  in my custom div :http://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/1fLnu517/

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue solve with this.

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
        revert: true,
        appendTo: "body",
        helper: 'clone',
        start: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).fadeTo(0, 1);
        }
    });
```

[Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/5DCZw/1120/)

I have edited my answer to set text instead of innerhtml.